# In Linux, how to classify a process as I/O bound or memory bound at runtime?

Tags: linux

I'm currently developing an application in Linux which needs  to classify some processes as network I/O bound or memory bound at runtime. Instead of using some tool such as **iotop**, I need to identify whether a process is network I/O bound or not in my code. I tried to use the information available through ***/proc***, but I can not find network I/O statistics there. So, are there any other ways I can get network I/O statistics of a process? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you taken a look at how iftop is implemented?

Comment: No, I haven't. Well, it's a good idea to learn from source codes. Thank you!

Comment: Can you even get a process network IO (on a vanilla kernel)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `cat /proc/pid/io` at a certain frequence.

And delta write/read bytes tell whether the pid is I/O bound. (Of course according to your own benchmark.)

[link to similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206252/know-which-process-does-i-o-without-iotop)

Comment: Tank you for your answer! But according to [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), the **/proc/pid/io**  file contains disk I/O statistics for the process, not the network I/O statistics.